# Maven Release Plugin - Multi-module project skipping modules

Tags: maven-release-plugin

I am using maven-release-plugin on a multi-module project with the following layout:

```
ROOT/
  + parent
  + module1
  + module2
```

In the `parent`'s pom, the child modules configured using `modules` element. Each one of the projects are configured to use the plugin with basic configuration and a tag base for each. I have the following problems:

- When I run `mvn release:prepare` on `parent`, after the line that says `Checking for snapshot dependencies ...`, I receive no prompt to enter the versions. If I press `Enter` for the number of questions it requires answer, it continues. Why do not I receive prompts on the screen? (The same thing happens if run with `-DdryRun=true`)
- After running `mvn release:prepare` (with or without `-DdryRun=true`), the `release:prepare` is ***SKIPPED*** for the child modules.

I am using the basic configuration on the plugin's guide. I'd be thankful for any ideas or clues of what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the lack of prompts, are you running mvn through a pipe?  This happened to me when I was using a script to do colour highlighting of Maven's log output, because Maven doesn't output a newline after the prompt.

By the way, you may be able to use mvn's -B option to run in batch mode; maven-release-plugin will use the default values instead of prompting.

Comment: Colorizing pipe! That was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to perform release:prepare on child modules?

Comment: Is there a way to perform release:prepare on child modules?